# Red Hat ActiveMQ 6: inner orchestration from topic to queues so that messages are reproduced from topic to queues

Tags: activemq-classic

[image]

Applications connecting to our AMQ-based platform may subscribe to different source queues to consume messages, but client wants that config to be constant.

The ideal solution would be, he/she only connects to his/her queue(target queue), and when he wants to subscribe to another source queue, sends a request to us, and we internally connects his target queue to that source queue he/she needs, so he does not needs to do any config change. Is there some native ways in Red Hat AMQ 6 to do this orchestration of messages from topics to queues? (Of course we need an API for this kind of requests)

[image]

I see this question: [how to bridge a topic and queue in activemq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469704/how-to-bridge-a-topic-and-queue-in-activemq) but seems only send messages from queues to topics. Client needs to change to subscribe to that topic, changing his/her config.

Comment: FWIW, there is no such thing as "ActiveMQ 6."

Comment: Sorry, I meant Red Hat AMQ 6 which uses Apache ActiveMQ 5.x

Answer (score 0):

There is no API or mechanism in ActiveMQ to dynamically shift subscriptions from one Topic or Queue to another without the client having to be reconfigured.

Comment: Could mirroring queues, virtual topics and other features be combined in some way so that it achieves such purpose? For example if we turn on virtual topics, enterprise queue will publish messages to some topic, so the first half is done. But I am not aware of the second half. Does not need to shift, it can reproduce/mirror.